# Gnuplot 3d mesh from XYZ data

Tags: gnuplot

I have data in from a 3d outline scan with the following layout:

376 331 213

372 331 213

...

354 182 217

357 182 217

where all xyz points are points along each z point along the surface:

**splot 'file.dat' with lines gives:**
[image: splot 'file.dat' with lines gives:]

Splot with pm3d gives a warning: Single Isoline (scan) is not enough for a pm3d plot.

**What parameters can be used to interpolate the XYZ to a 3d mesh like this?**

[image]

Something like a 3d convex hull interpolation of all points.

Comment: Although it's an old question... Please provide meaningful example data for testing and to see how exactly your data it organized, e.g. do you have empty lines in your data?